# What are allowed and not allowed columns in Adempiere web service createData call

Tags: adempiere, idempiere

I created a web service in Idempiere, added input params, etc, for createData service for one table. While calling that service from SoapUI, I am getting the column not allowed message for one of the columns. What does it mean? which columns are allowed and which are not allowed, how to know?

I googled before posting here, but I couldn't find an answer to my doubt.

**Edited:**
**Solution:** The column name to be used in SOAP request should be the first part i.e., the string before the underscore, which is used in the Idempiere Web Service Field Input.

Answer (score 0):

The allowed columns are defined in the window *Web Service Security*, tab *Web Service Field Input*.

For example: this is a screenshot taken from http://test-postgresql.idempiere.org/webui/index.zul?Action=Zoom&AD_Table_ID=53164&Record_ID=50001

[image: screenshot from Web Service Security]

Comment: Hi CarlosRuiz! Thanks for the reply. I tried the same, i.e., used column name from the web service field input tab...and also tried the column name used in the table. Both didn't work.

Comment: Okay, I found the problem.....I used full name like Name_Name where we need to use Name. After I change the parameter accordingly in the SOAP request, it worked fine.